# Помогите пожалуйста с таймером С#

Tags: c#

Решил создать таймер с диалоговым окном об окончании времени. Мысль заключается в том, чтобы спустя час, выводилось диалоговое окно о том, чтобы сделать перерыв, но я не силен в разработке и прошу у вас помощи.

Вот код таймера, но не знаю как сделать автостоп и диалоговое окно.

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    int i = 0;

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        i++;

        label1.Text = i.ToString();
    }

    private void Start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: [Как правильно писать «чтобы» или «что бы»?](http://chtoby-pravilno.ru/chtoby/)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Исправил, раз это вам настолько важно. Но вместо исправление моей грамматики, было бы лучше, если бы вы обратили внимание на вопрос.

Comment: показать текст юзеру  - ```MessageBox.Show```, остановить таймер ```timer.enabled=false```

Comment: Перед стартом таймера задать интервал в один час: `timer.Interval = 3600000;`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский при выставлении интервала в пару секунд, таймер продолжает работать.

Comment: @tym32167 мне нужна команда которая автоматически его остановит по окончанию заданного времени.

Comment: Ну так сделайте в обработчике ```timer1_Tick``` -> ```timer1.Enabled = false;```

Comment: @tym32167 уже сам разобрался при помощи другой команды, спасибо

Comment: @tym32167 было бы неплохо теперь узнать, как его сбросить

Comment: Я не знаю, какой вы таймер используете, но если для винформ, то есть справка на русском https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.timer(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}
int i = 0;

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    i++;
    label1.Text = i.ToString();
    if(i==3600)
    {
        timer1.Enabled = false;
        MessageBox.Show("Прошел 1 час");
    }
}

private void Start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer1.Interval = 1000;
    i = 0;
    timer1.Enabled = true;
}
```